# How to declare an uint8_t "string" in a struct?

Tags: c, struct

Creating an uint8_t "string" works fine for me:

```
uint8_t myString[] = "Foo";
```

However when I try to declare it in a struct, it does not work:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct{
    uint32_t id;
    uint8_t name[];
    uint16_t life;
    uint16_t mana;
    uint16_t fist;
    uint16_t shielding;
} player;

#endif // PLAYER_H_
```

I get a compilation message saying: *Field has incomplete type uint8_t[]*.

What am I missing here guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  uint8_t name[];
```

You have not mentioned size here , either mention size of `name`. You cannot create array of unknown size in somewhere middle of your structure.

```
uint8_t name[50];                // this could do
```

And you could initialize it like this -

```
player p1={.name="hello"};
```

Or use `memcpy` .

Comment: you can't initialize in a typedef.

Comment: @Jasen yeah I gave a run , It wont . Thanks !! :-)

Comment: Well, you actually **can**. Use a flexible array member. It has to be the last member, though.

Comment: @Olaf Yes , that I didn't mention in answer that unknown sized array could not be in middle of struct that's what made it ambiguous  :-) ,

Comment: Well, placing the array at the end is certainly the lesser modification here. This would be different if there was more than one such array in the struct.

Comment: @Olaf Certainly that would be different  , than this one  their changes would be necessary :-)

Comment: I't not quite clear what you mean. However, changes would be necessary anyway. However, OP clearly asks for a `struct` with a non-constant size. And that can only be accomplished with a flexible array member, not a fixed size array.

Comment: @Olaf Well , I don't see OP asked insisted on it , but **flexible array member would be more suited** . (_clearly it didn't crossed my mind_) :)

Comment: Note, the flexible array as the last member is `static`, so if he is creating an array of `players`, then they will all have the same `name`...

Answer (score 2):

You have to give `name` a size inside the string. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know how large the struct is.

When declaring a variable like

```
uint8_t myString[] = "Foo";
```

the compiler can figure the size out from the size of `"Foo"`, but if you declare an array without an initial value, *you* have to tell the size.

---

(The comments question if a `uint8_t` array can really be initialized with a string. On systems where `char` is unsigned, `uint8_t` *could* be a typedef for `char`.)

Comment: did that compile for you?

Comment: @Jasen - I don't know if the OP is on a system where `char` is signed or unsigned. I trust the statement that the first version works.

Comment: Why not use a flexible array member?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have an array of indeterminate size in a struct it must be the last element of the struct, and when allocating memory for the struct you must allocate extra for the array contents.

Comment: That is called a flexible array member. You should elaborate a bit more on its usage and drawbacks. With that it would be the only correct answer until now.